# Setting the route parameter in the middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-binding, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I am developing a Laravel application. I am doing route model binding in the middleware.

I have the routes like this

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'department/{department}', 'middleware' => [ 'auth.department' ] ], function () {
    Route::post('employee/create', 'EmployeeController@store')->name('employees.store');
});
```

This is my auth.department middleware (AuthDepartment)

```
class AuthDepartment
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $department = Department::find($request->department);
        //do something with the department
        //I want to set the $department (Department model) in the place of {department} in the route.


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is EmployeeController

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller {
    public function store($department)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I am using $department parameter to get the department id from the route. But instead of getting the integer as the parameter, I want to bind the model like this.

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller {
     public function store(Department $department)
     {
     }
}
```

With my current code, it is not working. I tried to set the route parameter in the middleware as follow to match (bind model) the value in the action.

```
$request->route()->setParameter('department', $department)
```

But it is just not working. How can I set/ replace the route parameter with a model in the middleware which can be binded to the parameter in the action of the controller? Is it possible? What could be the better approach?

If I used

```
$request->route()->setParameter('department', $department)
```

to set the parameter, I cannot set type in the action of the controller like this.

```
store(Department $department)
```

But this is fine

```
 store(Department $department)
```

But I want this

```
store(Department $department)
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already has this built in. It is called Route Model Binding.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

Remove the middleware and instead keep your controller as it is. Laravel will automatically use the ID in the request to find the model and give you an instance of it. If the model cannot be found, Laravel will throw a 404 response for you.

Comment: But the thing is how would u get that model value in the middleware? It is not binding in the middleware.

Comment: Why do you need the model value in the middleware?

Comment: Cause I have to pass the value in the route all the time to access to the specific part of my application. I am creating the middleware for that instead.